# Does xcodebuild command have some options about C++ compile options?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++, xcodebuild

When I used Xcode 4.6 preview verion or xcodebuild command, I had a such error below.

```
invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier
```

However When I used Xcode4, there were no errors.

I don't have much knowledge about C++ and the compiler, so I couldn't find the answer from Internet.

Would you tell me how can I avoid the error with xcodebuild command?

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke xcodebuild from the cmd-line, it ***should*** be essentially the same as building the target from within Xcode's IDE.

The only difference that I can think of is that running from the cmd-line will default to Release configuration, whereas inside the IDE will probably use debug. (These can be overridden in both cases).

Could it be that you have a different C++ flags for Debug and Release, and this is making it not work? Try building your project with Release mode inside the IDE, and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you answer! I ran xcodebuild with debug target option, but has same error too... So I'll try other option and compare with using Xcode.